# Ominiauth Youtube Login - Redirect to create youtube channel on 401 nolinkedoutubeaccount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, youtube, youtube-api, omniauth

I am using omniauth youtube and google oauth2 gems for loggin in via youtube. This all works fine but on the condition that the user has already created a youtube channel with the account their are trying to log in with.

When the user tries to log in and authorize without a youtube channel created it errors out with the following message:

```
OAuth2::Error

    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>NoLinkedYouTubeAccount</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
    <H1>NoLinkedYouTubeAccount</H1>
    <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

How could I handle this error so that the user is either sent to their youtube account where they can create their youtube channel and then be redirected back to the site with valid login credentials or to be sent back to a page which gives instructions on how to create a youtube channel and try again?

My code is as follows:

user.rb

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.picture = auth.info.image
      user.save!
      end
    end
```

session_controller:

```
def create
      user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Signed in"
    end

    def destroy
      session[:user_id] = nil
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Signed out"
    end

    def failure
    end
```

log in form

```
<% if current_user %>
        Logged in as <b><%= current_user.name %></b>
            <%=  image_tag current_user.picture %><br>
            <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path %>
        <% else %>
            Sign in with <%= link_to image_tag('youtube.png'), "/auth/youtube" %>
        <% end %>
```

routes

```
match 'auth/youtube/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

**UPDATE**
I got this working with help from a small blog, the address which i will link to. This solution adds a failure message to the url of the auth/failure route and redirects correctly to a youtube link page with instructions.

I added the following to omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.on_failure do |env|
  exception = env['omniauth.error']
  error_type = env['omniauth.error.type']
  strategy = env['omniauth.error.strategy']

  Rails.logger.error("OmniAuth Error (#{error_type}): #{exception.inspect}")
    #ErrorNotifier.exception(exception, :strategy => strategy.inspect, :error_type => error_type)

  new_path = "#{env['SCRIPT_NAME']}#{OmniAuth.config.path_prefix}/failure?message=#{error_type}"

  [301, {'Location' => new_path, 'Content-Type'=> 'text/html'}, []]
end
```

which displays the authorisation error in the auth/failure url and added this to my routes.rb

```
match 'auth/failure', to: 'static_pages#youtube'
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm...you can set a condition to your model function tht

```
if user = User.find_by_id(id)
  user
else 
  //procceed with your code to link the account to utube
```

Comment: hi Nich, should this code be in the controller? so if the user is saved return to the homepage otherwise go to this instructions page?

Comment: hmm, you can put it in a function in the model like what you actually did,just put a condition in your logic, then in the controller just invoke this function